# How to apply Combs Method?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, rules, fuzzy-logic

I'm studying combs method, for reducing the "combinatorial explosion" of fuzzy logic rules. There's an example, taken from "Programming Game AI from example" (written by Mat Buckland) :

> ***The theory behind the Combs method works on the principle that a rule such as:***
>
> IF Target_Far AND Ammo_Loads THEN Desirable
>
> is logically equivalent to: IF Target_Far THEN Desirable OR IF
>   Ammo_Loads THEN Desirable
>
> Using this principle, a rule base can be defined that contains only
>   one rule per consequent member set. For example, the nine rules for
>   the desirability of the rocket launcher given previously:
>
> Rule 1. IF Target_Far AND Ammo_Loads THEN Desirable
>
> Rule 2. IF Target_Far AND Ammo_Okay THEN Undesirable
>
> Rule 3. IF Target_Far AND Ammo_Low THEN Undesirable
>
> Rule 4. IF Target_Medium AND Ammo_Loads THEN VeryDesirable
>
> Rule 5. IF Target_Medium AND Ammo_Okay THEN VeryDesirable
>
> Rule 6. IF Target_Medium AND Ammo_Low THEN Desirable
>
> Rule 7. IF Target_Close AND Ammo_Loads THEN Undesirable
>
> Rule 8. IF Target_Close AND Ammo_Okay THEN Undesirable
>
> Rule 9. IF Target_Close AND Ammo_Low THEN Undesirable
>
> ***can be reduced to six rules:***
>
> Rule 1. IF Target_Close THEN Undesirable
>
> Rule 2. IF Target_Medium THEN VeryDesirable
>
> Rule 3. IF Target_Far THEN Undesirable
>
> Rule 4. IF Ammo_Low THEN Undesirable
>
> Rule 5. IF Ammo_Okay THEN Desirable
>
> Rule 6. IF Ammo_Loads THEN VeryDesirable

I don't understand how he reduced those rules! I've split every starting rule in two parts (applying the principle written in the beginning A and B => C is equivalent to A => C OR B => C). Now is there a pattern to follow, or the final 6 rules are independent from the starting 9?

Answer (score 0):

the first problem is an operator. it's not just AND it's IF THEN... 
here you can find more about IF/THEN operator : http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ramsey/Logic/IfThen.html

but the question "how to reduce" remains open